# Python pip install error, "invalid syntax"

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, pip

I am attempting to install various python libraries on a very old ubuntu machine however keep running into the same error when using pip:

for example:
`$ pip install pygame`

Gives the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/syn/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/syn/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong or how I can fix this?

Comment: Which terminal you are using? I assume you already installed pip

Comment: I am using the standard ubuntu (16.04) terminal

Comment: Did you installed pip? and Where do you run pip commands? It looks like you run pip commands in python file

Comment: I should add that I have managed to install libraries previously (mingus & keyboard) but can't install any others at the moment

Comment: Yes I have installed pip and I am running it in terminal, not python console

Comment: error shows that it uses `Python 3.5`  - `/home/syn/.local/lib/python3.5/...` - but code has `f-string` - `write(f"ERROR: {exc}")` - which needs `Python 3.6`